# git rebase -i HEAD~3 выдаёт ошибку

Tags: visual-studio, git

Решил использовать `git rebase -i HEAD~3` для слияния трёх коммитов, но получил следующую ошибку (ниже). Помогите решить эту проблему.

> $ git rebase -i HEAD~3
>
> */mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: eval: line 255: syntax error near unexpected token '('*
>
> */mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: eval: line 255: ‘C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe "$@"’*

**Дополнительная информация:**

Использую GitExtensions в качестве оболочки для работы с git и привязал к этому делу vsdiffmerge в качестве инструмента слияния.

Не знаю почему, но в сообщении указан путь установки Visual Studio. Версия Visual Studio: 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Попробуйте перепроверить ваш .gitconfig на наличие ошибок, кавычки, слеши и т.д. http://www.khokhlin.ru/2014/04/git-extensions-syntax-error-near.html

Comment: @a.chugunov, .gitconfig - отсутствует.

Comment: Сделайте видимыми скрытые файлы посмотрите каталог пользователя или своего репозитория для нахождения gitconfig

Answer (score 1):

Как будто бы ошибка где-то в самом приложении git. Вместо git rebase -i можно сделать так:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3.
# указатель HEAD переставляется на три коммита назад
# изменения из этих коммитов остались и уже проиндексированы (добавлены)
# можно делать коммит:

git commit 
# пишем сообщение нового коммита
```